# помогите исправить ошибку с выражением при вызове функции

Tags: c++

"Выражение должно иметь тип указателя на объект"
как исправить ошибку при вызове функции с циклом

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<iostream>

int vvodmass(int a[], int  size)
{
    printf("ввод массива");
    int ch = 0;
    printf("ввод рандомности массива");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % ch;
    }
    return 0;
}

int vyvodmass(int a[], int size) {
    printf("вывод массива");
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int vvodmass(x[]);
}
```

Comment: не ясно, что именно вы хотите, поясните более подробно

Comment: Ну а где сам **массив**, который вы собрались передавать в функцию? `x` - просто `int`, но никак не массив. А вы должны передать массив и его размер. Так что сразу встает вопрос об авторстве кода... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, в функции `main` Вы должны объявить переменную, к примеру `size`, в которой должно храниться целочисленное значение, для дальнейшего объявления массива. Вместо `int x = 0;`, Вы должны написать `int x[size];`, где `size` количество элементов массива. Также Вы должны исправить вызов функции, вместо `int vvodmass(x[]);` напишите `vvodmass(x, size);`.

Примечания:
Следующее, что я заметил, это то, что в циклах `for` Вы пробегаетесь с `int = 0` и до `i <= size`, то есть когда Вы заполняете массив, вместо `size` элементов, Вы заполняете `size + 1` элементов(Не забывайте про `int = 0`!). В результате вы выходите за границы массива, что приведёт к UB(Undefined Behavior - Неопределённое Поведение).
Функции `vvodmass` и `vyvodmass` возвращают `0`, хотя по сути, вы никуда это значение не присваиваете, поэтому целесообразно было бы использовать тип фунцкии `void` и убрать последние строки `return 0;`, хотя не принципиально.

Comment: Поправочка: `size` должно быть константой, значение которой известно на момент компиляции.

Comment: @EOF Верно, но видно, что человек в этом новенький и пока не стоит ему грузить голову `#define`'ом

Comment: Именно. Если человек в этом новенький, то лучше научить правильно, чтобы он не думал, что использование VLA в С++ - это норма. Ну и не обязательно использовать `#define`.